# Alternative to Get-Random method in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, random, methods, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

There is a text file which contains many fields. My purpose is to update the int field with a new random number everytime my script runs and and then save the text file. By this, the number should always be different than the last run, when i open the script again.

For example: I want to update the count field "152" to say "455", then run my script, save the file. Next, time i want it to change to "788", for ex and so on....

```
"Test1", "05/08/18", "152", "Type1"

$Count = Get-Random -Maximum 999
```

However, i noticed a weird thing, that when i use the `Get-Random` method in my script, it adds extra dummy numbers into other fields(records) in my text file.

My record looked like this:

```
 "Tes1523t1", "05/08/18", "152", "Type3241"
```

Now, is there any other alternative to change a number everytime with using Random method?

Comment: Show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your script which demonstrates this problem. Because `Get-Random` on its own shouldn't be doing anything like what you describe - it's far more likely that it's something else in the code you wrote.

Comment: As the above comment suggests, there isn't enough information here to understand the problem.  Try editing your question and posting your script.  There is no way to know how you're getting the output that you are without seeing your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

For the test, if i remove the date e.g `05/08/18` you can use simple regex with `Get-Random`, like this:

```
@("Test1", "152", "Type1") | % {
    $_ -replace "\d+",(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 999)
}

Test922
748
Type603
```

To improve this you need to identify the characters that you want to replace and exclude the one you don't, the `\d+` will replace any number, if you will add the date it will change it as well, so you need to find the correct regex pattern to use the replace correctly,

Comment: i cant use random method.

Comment: what do you mean `i cant use random method`?